# Ajax delete with laravel 500 internal error

Tags: javascript

Hi there I am new on coding so forgive me if I am asking too much, I have this problem here this is my HTML code on blade laravel:

```
<button type="button" id="removecollaborator" value="{{$bank_id}}" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm delete-colaboration-button" 
                                 title="@lang('buttons.remove_option')">
                                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                            </button>
```

and here I have my ajax js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", "button[id=removecollaborator]", function (data) {

            var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this collaborator?");
            if (result) {

                var bankid = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({

                    method: "POST",
                    url: "{{ url('/banks/delete-bank-collaborators') }}",
                    data: {
                        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        bank_id: bankid
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        $("button[id=removecollaborator][value=" + bankid + "]").parent().parent().parent().parent().fadeOut('slow');

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

And here I have the controller:

```
 public function deleteCollaborator(){ 

        if(request()->ajax()) {

            $bank_id = request()->input('bank_id');
            $bank_invites = BankInvite::select('id')->where('bank_id', $bank_id)->get()->toArray();
            BankInvitedUser::whereIn('bank_invites_id', $bank_invites)->delete();


            return response()->json(Lang::get('general.bank_deleted'));
        }
```

It does not work I do not know why it returns Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). so it is the success but I think in the controller I have the problem can someone help me, please..?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
deleteCollaborator(){
```

with

```
deleteCollaborator(Request $request){
```

also is your route a `Route::post()`?